# How to validate input length with Spring.net?

Tags: validation, spring.net

I cannot find any good information on how to validate input field length with Spring.net, but it must be possible.  Here is what I have tried:

```xml
<v:condition test="string.Length(InputField) > 2000" >
  <v:message id="Errors.TooLong2000" providers="InputField"/>
</v:condition>
```

But, that fails to get parsed by Spring.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your Value property is called `Text`:

```xml
<v:condition test="InputField.Text.Length &lt;= 2000" when="InputField.Text != null">
  <v:message id="Errors.TooLong2000" providers="InputField"/>
</v:condition>
```

Comment: Thanks!  My field was actually called "InputField", so this is the rule that worked:

`<v:condition test="InputField.Length &lt;= 2000" when="InputField!= null">
      <v:message id="Errors.TooLong2000" providers="InputField"/>
    </v:condition>`